# Adwords Track Offline Telephone Orders

Tags: google-ads-api

I would like to track orders that have been made offline by telephone. I m not interested to track only the orders that come from adwords extensions or ads.

Is there any way like UTM URL or by uploading a CSV file in order to achieve my goal?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for a solution to general business problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to have different telephone numbers for each source, then you need to have a system to track which phone numbers generate the most leads.

There are companies that will provide numbers, track calls to them and forward the call to your main line. There is no simple way of connecting a particular click from your website with a particular "Incoming" phone enquiry.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you understood completely my question. It's not necessary for me to have an automated system. 
I want manually to import the order with its value when a telephone order occurs, in order to have information about the revenue.
I'm asking if there is any way like UTM URL (import data to Google Analytics) to import and edit data in Adwords.